# Как выровнять картинку с неизвестной высотой по вертикали?

Tags: css

Есть блоки для миниатюр. Высота блоков 180px. Нужно растягивать миниатюры по ширине, а по высоте центрировать. Размеры картинок для миниатюр заведомо неизвестны и всегда разные.

```
<div style="width:100%; height:180px; overflow:hidden;">
    <img src="https://site.ru/img.jpg">
</div>
```

Как решить данную задачу?

Comment: Извините, ответил слишком поспешно. Решение было сырое, удалил ответ

Answer (score 1):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
}

body:before, span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<span>Put your image<br>instead of this span</span>
```

Comment: Зачем before для body? Уже делал display: inline-block; и  vertical-align: middle;, но картинка по прежнему отталкивается от верхнего края.

Comment: @АгнаманШаманский, вот именно для этого `before`. У меня же по центру ;)

Comment: @АгнаманШаманский, обеспечивает высоту строки.

Comment: Но у меня картинка выше, чем контейнер (180px).

Comment: @АгнаманШаманский, и как же ты хочешь её отцентрировать?

Comment: уже ответил сам себе.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал так:

```
<div style="width:100%; height:180px; overflow:hidden; position: relative;">
    <img src="https://site.ru/img.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; transform: translateY(-50%);
top: 50%; position: relative;">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div style="width:100%; height:180px; overflow:hidden;">
    <img style="width:auto; height:180px; src="https://site.ru/img.jpg">
</div>
```

или так ( а то не совсем понял)

```
<div style="width:100%; height:180px; overflow:hidden;">
    <img style="width:100%; height:auto; src="https://site.ru/img.jpg">
</div>
```

Попробуй сделать как-то так, из стилями картинки

Comment: Уже сделано как во втором варианте. Картинка прижимается сверху.